# Switching a boolean variable (applied)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, boolean

I am trying to make a game (tacky, I know) and given the fact that I am not all that good with javascript/jquery I've managed to become stuck with switching a boolean variable. I tried the whole var = !var (no idea what that means) but some speculated it only works in objective C (again, no idea). I have made a JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/clarinetking/mLG6c/1/ and it works at the moment but I want to add a variable to all my objects called 'equip' and have it start out as false and be switched to true whenever the correct button is pressed.

```
var sword = {
nam:'Sword',
atk:5,
def:1,
spd:-1,
type:'LeftH',
//equip = false  
};
```

etc

```
switch ( $(this).attr('id') ) {
        case 'equipsword':
            atk += sword.atk;
            def += sword.def;
            spd += sword.spd;
            //insert equip switch here
            break;
```

Comment: yes `!` works in javascript not just C, the `!`, is the NOT operator, it basically takes the opposite of whatever it is in front of, so `!true === false`, `!false === true`, this also goes for truthy/falsy values, `!null === true`, `!0 === true`, `!15 === false`, `!"" === true`

Comment: That's brilliant! I've tried it and it didn't work though so hopefully someone will come along and use it practically so I can see how much of an idiot I've been

Comment: All you really want to do is set sword.equip to true, right? I don't think you really need `!` here. If you wanted clicking sword to toggle it equipped or not equipped, you'll need to do more than just toggle the equip value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes `!` works in javascript not just C, the `!`, is the NOT operator, it basically takes the opposite of whatever it is in front of, so:

```
!true === false
!false === true
```

this also goes for truthy/falsy values:

```
!null === true
!0 === true
!15 === false
!"" === true
```

So to toggle a boolean value just use the following:

```
var sword = {
   nam:'Sword',
   atk:5,
   def:1,
   spd:-1,
   type:'LeftH',
   equip:false  
};    
switch ( $(this).attr('id') ) {
    case 'equipsword':
        atk += sword.atk;
        def += sword.def;
        spd += sword.spd;
        sword.equip = !sword.equip;
        break;
```

but since case 'equipsword' from the looks of it will only be triggered when equipping and not unequipping might as well just do `sword.equip = true;`, especially since there might be a chance that some other code might change the value of `equip`, and then the toggle would not work as expected for instance if the following code ran before the equipsword case was triggered:

```
function someFunctionThatGetsCalled(){
   sword.equip = true;
}
```

it would cause equip to be true and then when the equipsword case is triggered sword.equip would then become false because its using the `!sword.equip` toggle.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do more than just !bool here, you'll want to reverse the stat changes too. For example:

```
        if (sword.equip) {
            atk -= sword.atk;
            def -= sword.def;
            spd -= sword.spd;
        }
        else {
            atk += sword.atk;
            def += sword.def;
            spd += sword.spd;
        }
        sword.equip = !sword.equip;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mLG6c/2/

Note, you should likely refactor this code so that you don't need the switch statement, since the action you are performing for each piece of equipment is identical.